# CSS Text appearing

Tags: html, css

I want that text is appearing when the page is being load (example: [here](http://adstyl.es/#/home)).

How to do this? After some research, I have this (but it doesn't work):

```css
#text p {
  font-size: 21px;
  text-align: center;
  animation: appear 2s;
  -moz-animation: appear 2s;
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation: appear 2s;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-animation: appear 2s;
  /* Opera */
}
@keyframes appear {
  from {
    left: -100px;
  }
  to {
    left: 315px;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes appear {
  /* Firefox */
  from {
    left: -100px;
  }
  to {
    left: 315px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes appear {
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  from {
    left: -100px;
  }
  to {
    left: 315px;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes appear {
  /* Opera */
  from {
    left: -100px;
  }
  to {
    left: 315px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="text">
  <p>Test for the Text</p>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong, and how to correct that?

Comment: It may have to do with the `position` property for `#text p`. By default the value is `static` and the `left` property doesn't affect statically positioned elements. If you set `position` to for instance `relative` the animation will work.

Comment: did you add animation css

Comment: @LuudJacobs Thanks, now I can see some animation, but how to let it appear from the left? Like on the example.

Comment: Yes, did that. @JishnuVS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were nearly there, you need to absolutely position your `p` in order to animate the `left` property, I have also made it `inline-block` so the text starts off the screen (otherwise as you have the p tag as align center, you would need to make sure your starting left position was greater than half the width of the screen)

```css
#text p {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 21px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  animation: appear 2s;
  left: 315px;
}
@keyframes appear {
  from {
    left: -100px;
  }
  to {
    left: 315px;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes appear {
  /* Firefox */
  from {
    left: -100px;
  }
  to {
    left: 315px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes appear {
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  from {
    left: -100px;
  }
  to {
    left: 315px;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes appear {
  /* Opera */
  from {
    left: -100px;
  }
  to {
    left: 315px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="text">
  <p>Test for the Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to keep it more to the right, instead of going back to the left?

Comment: See edit, you need to also add the finishing left position to the initial styles,  or are you wanting it to finish in the center of the page?